# Spanning Text across lines in DIV style Menu

Tags: html, css, html-table, display

So first of all i'd like to apologize for code dumping below, however I think it's relevant to the question...

I have a lovely menu over at [LeedsHydroponics.com/](http://leedshydroponics.com/) however I am having some issues with my menu redesign. We've added a load of new categories and as such the menu is now too large for the current situation. Ideally i'd like to mod the menu so that the text changes from looking like its current situation where the text spans a single line [image: this is how it currently looks]

to being more like the first few items of this where the text spans multiple lines [image: a moch up i've manually made]

or perhaps a better example would be something like this [image: best example i can find]

hopefully if I can get this working, we should be able to just about fit all 16 catagories on the menu... Although it may be a struggle haha...

Thanks in anticipation !!

Hopefully the ideas discussed will also help others with similar DIV menu formatting issues

```css
.pt_custommenu {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: url("../images/bg-menu.gif") repeat-x;
}
.pt_custommenu div.pt_menu {
    float: left;
    background: url("../images/bg-right-menu.png") no-repeat right;
}
.pt_custommenu div.pt_menu .parentMenu a,
.pt_custommenu div.pt_menu .parentMenu span.block-title{
 padding: 0px 4px;
 margin:0 2px 0 1px;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 53px;
 float:left;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.pt_custommenu div.pt_menu.active {
    /*background:url("../images/bg-hover-menu.png") repeat-x 0 0;*/
   /* background:#000;
    margin-right:2px;*/
}
.pt_custommenu div.popup {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3000;
    background-color:#fb5b06;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
}
.pt_custommenu div.pt_menu .parentMenu a:hover,
.pt_custommenu div.pt_menu .parentMenu span.block-title:hover,
.pt_custommenu #pt_menu_link ul li a.act,
.pt_custommenu #pt_menu_link ul li a:hover {
    background:url("../images/bg-hover-menu.png") repeat-x 0 0;
    margin:0 2px 0 1px;
}
#pt_menu_pt_item_menu_custom_menu.active span {
    background:url("../images/bg-hover-menu.png") repeat-x 0 0;
    margin: 0 2px 0 1px;
}
.pt_custommenu div.pt_menu.act a, .pt_custommenu div.pt_menu.active .parentMenu a{
    background:url("../images/bg-hover-menu.png") repeat-x 0 0;
}
#pt_menu_home a {margin: 0 2px 0 0; background: url("../images/bg-home.png") no-repeat 50% 45%; text-indent: -9999px; width: 30px; }
#pt_menu_home a:hover { background: url("../images/bg-home.png") no-repeat 50% 45% #FB7906;   }
#pt_menu_home.act {background: url("../images/bg-right-menu.png") no-repeat scroll right center #FB7906; } 
.pt_custommenu div.popup a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    line-height: 32px;
}
.header-menu {width: 100%; margin: 0 0 20px;}

.pt_custommenu .itemMenu h4.level1,
.pt_custommenu .itemMenu a.level1{
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
.pt_custommenu .itemMenu h4.level1,
.pt_custommenu .itemSubMenu h4.level2 span{
    color: #897725;
}
.pt_custommenu .itemSubMenu h4.level2,
.pt_custommenu .itemSubMenu a.level2,
.pt_custommenu .itemSubMenu h4.level3,
.pt_custommenu .itemSubMenu a.level3,
.pt_custommenu .itemMenu a.level1.nochild{
    background: url("../images/black-dot.jpg") no-repeat left center;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 8px;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.pt_custommenu .itemSubMenu a.level2:hover,
.pt_custommenu .itemMenu a.level1.nochild:hover{
    color: #000;
}
.pt_custommenu div.popup a.actParent {
    color: #4D4D4D;
}
.pt_custommenu div.popup a.act {
    color: #A52A2A !important;
}
.pt_custommenu div.column {
    float:left;
    width:200px; /* column width */
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.pt_custommenu div.column.last {
    border-right: 0 none;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.pt_custommenu div.itemSubMenu {
 
}

.pt_custommenu .block2{
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
 color:#fff;
}
.pt_custommenu div.popup .block1{
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.pt_custommenu div.popup .block1 .column{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
.pt_custommenu div.popup .blockright img{
    max-width: 100%;
} 

.pt_custommenu div.pt_menu .parentMenu p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.pt_custommenu #pt_menu_link{
    padding: 0;
}
.pt_custommenu #pt_menu_link .parentMenu ul li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
.pt_custommenu #pt_menu_link .parentMenu ul li a{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: block;
}
.pt_custommenu .clearBoth {
    clear:both;
}
@media (max-width: 1060px) {
    .pt_custommenu div.pt_menu .parentMenu a,
    .pt_custommenu div.pt_menu .parentMenu span.block-title{
 font-size: 13px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container visible-desktop">
    <div class="header-menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="pt_custommenu" class="pt_custommenu">
        <div id="pt_menu_home" class="pt_menu act">
<div class="parentMenu">
<a href="http://leedshydroponics.com/">
<span>Home</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>            <div id="pt_menu9" class="pt_menu">
<div class="parentMenu">
<a href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients.html">
<span>NUTRIENTS</span>
</a>
</div>
<div id="popup9" class="popup" style="width: 410px; top: 45px; left: 40px; display: none;">
<div class="block1" id="block19" style="width: 410px;">
<div class="column first col1"><div class="itemMenu level1"><a class="itemMenuName level1" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives.html"><span>Nutrients&nbsp;and&nbsp;Additives</span></a><div class="itemSubMenu level1"><div class="itemMenu level2"><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/advanced-nutrients.html"><span>Advanced&nbsp;Nutrients</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/atami.html"><span>Atami</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/biobizz.html"><span>Biobizz</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/boontabud.html"><span>Boontabud</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/bud-link.html"><span>Bud&nbsp;Link</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/buddhas-tree.html"><span>Buddhas&nbsp;Tree</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/canadian-xpress.html"><span>Canadian&nbsp;Xpress</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/canna.html"><span>Canna</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/cyco-nutrients.html"><span>Cyco&nbsp;Nutrients</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/dutch-pro.html"><span>Dutch&nbsp;Pro</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/dutchmaster.html"><span>Dutchmaster</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/flair-form.html"><span>Flair&nbsp;Form</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/flower-dragon.html"><span>Flower&nbsp;Dragon</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/foxfarm.html"><span>Foxfarm</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/future-harvest.html"><span>Future&nbsp;Harvest</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/g-e-t.html"><span>G.E.T</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/great-white.html"><span>Great&nbsp;White</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/green-planet.html"><span>Green&nbsp;Planet</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/grotek.html"><span>Grotek</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/growstar.html"><span>Growstar</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/hesi.html"><span>Hesi</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/house-and-garden.html"><span>House&nbsp;And&nbsp;Garden</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/hygrozyme.html"><span>Hygrozyme</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/ionic.html"><span>IONIC</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/liquid-rox.html"><span>Liquid&nbsp;Rox</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/nitrozyme.html"><span>Nitrozyme</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/plant-magic.html"><span>Plant&nbsp;Magic</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/essentials.html"><span>ESSENTIALS</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/superthrive.html"><span>Superthrive</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/vitalink.html"><span>Vitalink</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/remo-nutrients.html"><span>Remo&nbsp;Nutrients</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-additives/rock-nutrients.html"><span>Rock&nbsp;Nutrients</span></a></div></div></div></div><div class="column last col2"><div class="itemMenu level1"><a class="itemMenuName level1" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-management.html"><span>Nutrient&nbsp;Management</span></a><div class="itemSubMenu level1"><div class="itemMenu level2"><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-management/combo-meters.html"><span>Combo&nbsp;Meters</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-management/ec-meters.html"><span>Ec&nbsp;Meters</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-management/nutrient-heaters.html"><span>Nutrient&nbsp;Heaters</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-management/ph-buffers.html"><span>pH&nbsp;Buffer's</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-management/ph-meters.html"><span>&nbsp;pH&nbsp;Meters</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-management/ph-test-indicator.html"><span>pH&nbsp;Test&nbsp;Indicator</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level2" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-management/ph-updown.html"><span>pH&nbsp;Up/Down</span></a><div class="itemSubMenu level2"><div class="itemMenu level3"><a class="itemMenuName level3" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-management/ph-updown/canna.html"><span>Canna</span></a><a class="itemMenuName level3" href="http://leedshydroponics.com/nutrients/nutrient-management/ph-updown/ph-updown.html"><span>Essentials</span></a></div></div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give list items (`<li>`) the following styles:

```
li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
nav {
display: block;
background-color: rgb(15,15,15);
width: 560px;
height: 50px;
}

nav img {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: rgb(255,191,0);
}

nav img {
float:left;
}

nav li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width:100px;
height: 50px;
line-height:25px;
padding: 0;
border-left:1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
border-right: 1px solid rgb(63,63,63);;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase
}

nav li:hover {
color: rgb(255,191,0);
background-color: rgb(31,31,31);
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<img />
<ul>
<li>The Quick</li>
<li>Brown Fox Jumps</li>
<li>Jumps Over Fox</li>
<li>The Lazy Brown</li>
<li>Dog The Quick</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Rounin however unfortunatly it's not quite what I am looking for...  If you see my screenshots I am ideally wanting something that wordwraps down the div and the div's width is prescribed by the longest word within... I've added another screenshot at the bottom the other screenshots at the top of my post above the code snippets to take a quick look at... Thanks

Comment: Aha. Yes. I saw your question late last night and wanted to illustrate the basic technique but didn't take note of your key phrase *first few items*. Give me a sec and I'll update the post above.